# Typedef to create a (fake) derived class in CRTP - impossible?

Tags: c++, c++14, typedef, crtp

How to alias a name that acts like a derived class in CRTP?

Is it (`Derived1`) simply impossible, and I have to fully create a new class (`Derived2`)?

```
template<class CRTP,class T>class Base{};

//These don't work.
//template<class T> using Derive1 = Base<Derive1<T>,T>;
//template<class T> using Derive1 = Base<Base,T>;
//template<class T> using Derive1 = Base<Base<T>,T>;
//template<class T> using Derive1 = Base<Base<Base<T>>,T>;

//This works.
template<class T> class Derive2 : public Base<Derive2<T>,T>{};
int main(){
    //Derive1<int> d1;
    Derive2<int> d2;
}
```

**[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b35eb7095c1f4017)**

There are a lot of questions related to `typedef` and `CRTP`, but I fail to find the one that matches mine.

Comment: typedef doesn't create new types. It only aliases types. Please explain why you expect any of those using statements to work

Comment: in CRTP you derive a class... Your "derive1" attempts do not use any derivation , it's unclear to me what you are asking

Comment: @AndyG Agree that it doesn't really create a new class.  I expect those statements to work because in many very simple cases, alias & (very simple) inheritance are quite exchangeable and yield the same result.   I am new to C++, though.

Comment: inheritance and not-inheritance are completely different

Comment: @M.M I think, after optimization, it is sometimes actually the same. Thus, I guess I can exploit it.  I am not really sure.

Comment: after optimization your program does nothing anyway ... that is not really relevant to anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aliases that attempt to recursively use `Base` will not work because each usage of `Base` will require you provide it 2 template parameters, but you never do, so that rules out these aliases:

```
template<class T> using Derive1 = Base<Base,T>;
template<class T> using Derive1 = Base<Base<T>,T>;
template<class T> using Derive1 = Base<Base<Base<T>>,T>;
```

Note that the 3<sup>rd</sup> one would have succeeded if you accepted another template argument to the alias:

```
template<class T, class U> using Derive1 = Base<Base<T, U>,T>;
```

Which leaves us with this:

```
template<class T> using Derive1 = Base<Derive1<T>,T>;
```

The reason this one doesn't work is because, on the right hand side of the `=` operator, there is no type named `Derive1` yet in existence, and on the left hand side, you use the same name as such a type. So would you end up with the same issue as before (recursive reference) except that this isn't possible because not only does a type named `Derive1` not already exist for usage in a template parameter, but even if it did the compiler would complain that you're trying to reuse the same symbol.

I suspect you're asking an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), so if you provide additional context on *how* you wanted to use these aliases, I can provide you an alternative solution.

Comment: No, I am just curious.  Thank.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with CRTP.

`using` creates an *alias*; you're attempting to create an entirely *new* and *separate* type.

It's not clear why you'd expect that to work, or why the shown solution is not sufficient.

So, yes, it's impossible.

Comment: Wisdom. Infinite wisdom. I love you (no that's not a sexual harrasment!)